# how to parallelize a function which is column bound?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a function, which does some operations on each DataFrame column and extracts a shorter series from it (in the original code there is some time consuming calculations going on)
Then it adds it to a dictionary before it goes on with the next columns.

In the end it creates a dataframe from the dictionary and manipulates its index.

How can I parallelize the loop in which each column is manipulated?

This is a less complicated reproducable sample of the code.

```
import pandas as pd
raw_df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[ 1.1 ]*100000, 
                       "B":[ 2.2 ]*100000,
                       "C":[ 3.3 ]*100000})

def preprocess_columns(raw_df, ):
 
    df = {}
    width = 137 
 
    for name in raw_df.columns:
        '''
        Note: the operations in this loop do not have a deep sense and are just for illustration of the function preprocess_columns. In the original code there are ~ 50 lines of list comprehensions etc.
        '''


        # 3. do some column operations. (actually theres more than just this operation)
        seriesF =  raw_df[[name]].dropna()
        afterDropping_indices = seriesF.index.copy(deep=True) 
        list_ = list(raw_df[name])[width:]  
        df[name]=pd.Series(list_.copy(), index=afterDropping_indices[width:]) 
    
    
    # create df from dict and reindex
    df=pd.concat(df,axis=1) 
    df=df.reindex(df.index[::-1])
    return df 
 
raw_df = preprocess_columns(raw_df )
```

Comment: It looks like the same result as ```df.drop((range(width)))```

Comment: @Johnny it does. sry for the misunderstanding. This code is just a structural example, to point out where specific the parallelization should be placed.

Comment: you almost cracked it, i.e. you can pass the `df[name]` as the index number and distribute it over your processing unit (considering your "do some operation" is independent of each other).

Comment: In case if you are looking for generic parallel implementation it's worth to look [modin](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for pandas

Comment: @Gahan how to do that? I just couldnt figure it out how to do that with mp.pool()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:
https://github.com/xieqihui/pandas-multiprocess

```
pip install pandas-multiprocess
```

```
from pandas_multiprocess import multi_process


args = {'width': 137}
result = multi_process(func=func, data=df, num_process=8, **args)
```

Comment: on pandas_multiprocess's github is says
"This function applies a function on each row of the input DataFrame by
    multiprocessing."
Is there a way to do that for columns?

Comment: @La-Li-Lu-Le-Loa ```pandas-multiprocess.multiprocess.py line:156  tasks.put(data.iloc[i, :])``` I think you can just cut columns and work

Comment: Sry i dont understand what you are saying (english is only my second tongue)

Comment: @La-Li-Lu-Le-Loa  Translation software determines my English level. My answers are usually not very direct and you need to do something about it.

Comment: that is no problem, brother. So the point is: I tried to implement it, but i could not figure out how to make it work for columns. Can you provide the working code on the example please?